# opencv почему не отображается картинка

Tags: python, linux, opencv, cv2, kubuntu

Я изучаю opencv. Я создал программу, которая должна просто отображать картинку. Когда я запускаю программу, она не выдает не одной ошибки, но картинка не отображается. Помогите мне, пожалуйста. Для общих сведений говорю, то что я использую Pycharm, и то что у меня Kubuntu 22.04.2. Вот мой код:

```py
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('<my path>')
cv2.imshow('Result',img)
cv2.waitKey(100000)
```

Comment: Попробуйте вот это https://stackoverflow.com/a/29584090/8324991 И тут ещё варианты https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64950340/cv2-imshow-is-not-working-properly-in-pycharm-macos

Comment: По вашему ответу у меня все осталось также, как и было. Проблема в том что Pycharm не отображает окно opencv

Comment: Да я понял, а по второй ссылке ответы пробовали? Хотя они для MAC OS, наверное не то.

Comment: Нет, не пробовал. Сейчас пробую

Comment: У меня kubuntu.

Comment: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1272: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage' Я сделал по второй ссылке и у меня вылезает такая ошибка

Comment: Все равно спасибо. Теперь я знаю от чего нужно отталкиваться